# Eclipse Zend Debugger PhP installation error

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, zend-debugger

Help. I am  starting to learn Php so I wanted to install the Zend Debugger. I already have Eclipse CDT(C/C++) installed so I wanted to install Zend Debugger plugin. When I install it it successfully processes till the end and then show an error!

```
An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=epp.package.cpp, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86 1.0.0.v20130521-1847 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file E:\Programmes\Eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe failed.
Can not remove : E:\Programmes\Eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

Screen shot here:

http://s24.postimg.org/fsvn2saj9/2014_03_23_14_59_10.png

Please Help! I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit. Please explain the steps as I am a noob LOL.

Answer (score -2):

very simple

if you have eclipse kepler, Please Update Eclipse

1. you must rename "eclipse.exe" -> "eclipse_1.exe"
2. Excute "eclipse_1.exe"
3. Kpler update
4. Update or install zend